# php decoding json using variable

Tags: php, json, variables, steam

I'm trying to display the price of each item displayed by using the market hash name, i can return the json just fine if master is set to a single item (eg. MP7 | Olive Plaid (Field-Tested)) but if I use a variable (checkgrd->marketh_hash_ name, decoded before from json too) like below, I seem to have a long page load and no results.

Any ideas regarding this or different method, basically all i'm doing is connecting gun and price.

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['xx'])){
$json_file = file_get_contents("http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/{$steam->response->players[0]->steamid}/inventory/json/730/2");
$jfo = json_decode($json_file);
$rgd = $jfo->rgDescriptions;
?>

<?PHP
foreach ($rgd as $write) {
$checkrgd = $write;
?>

<?PHP
$master = '' .$checkrgd->market_hash_name. '';
$url = file_get_contents("http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=".$master);
$url_1 = json_decode($url);

echo '<div id="item" onmouseover="nhpup.popup(\'<b>' .$checkrgd->name. '</b><br>' .($checkrgd->tags[5]->name). '<br><br>' .($checkrgd->tags[2]->name). '<br>' .$url_1->median_price. '\');" class="float_left" style="border-color: #' .($checkrgd->tags[4]->color). '; background: url(http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/economy/image/' .$checkrgd->icon_url. '/99fx66f) no-repeat center; background-size: 95%; text-align: center;"><div id="insideitem"><a href="http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=' .$checkrgd->market_hash_name. '">' .($checkrgd->tags[5]->name). '</a><div id="results"></div></div><br><br>';

if (($checkrgd->tags[3]->name) == 'StatTrak™') {
echo '<div id="insideitem" align="left" style="vertical-align:bottom;"><img src="images/stattrak.png" width="16" height="20"></div>';
}
echo '</div>';
?>

<?PHP
}}
?>
```

I edited the code to include the entire section. Sorry I was not more detailed straight up.
So the market_hash_name comes from the json_file. I want master to change for each item if possible, maybe i've got about it the complete wrong way even.

Comment: Try to urlencode the param before send

Comment: Please post the full code, or at least something that allows reproducing the issue.

Comment: youll need an API key to fully reproduce it but im sure if you change json_file to something to just get an output you should be good. - and thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Guess no one can help? :)

Answer (score 0):

`$master = '' .$checkrgd->market_hash_name. '';
$master = str_replace(' ','%20',$master);`

worked for me but the page load time is long with my Inventory ( 75 items loading time 20 sec ) and i dont check the items like bages and missions ..

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! Works, I did not realize the spaces was causing the issue. I do realize the load time is long, I'll be working on that!